# Get filenames of assetic files

Tags: php, symfony, assetic, cache-manifest

I'm building a web app using Symfony2 with Assetic. I would like to make a manifest file , but I have to manually add the file names to the list.

I can use PHP to get all static files (in [app/Bundle]/Resources/public), so I can generate of list of those files easily. But the other files (stylesheets, javascripts and images) are being generated by Assetic.

Is there a way to get a list of those generated files, so I can add them to a manifest-file?

Comment: Not sure how to get the generated name but you could always set the output filename yourself using `{% javascripts '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/js/*' output='js/compiled/main.js' %}` along with asset versioning for cache busting - http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#ref-framework-assets-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All files are registered in router

```
php app/console debug:router
```

You can see what the command is doing, by viewing the source: [Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/RouterDebugCommand.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/RouterDebugCommand.php). You can extract what you need.